# Inferring union type from keys in a collection of objects

Tags: typescript

I'm writing TypeScript code where I need to a list of object literals to describe a spec for a serialization format. I'm wondering if I can infer a union type that represents the values of a fixed key in the list, so that elsewhere, I can validate that the correct key was used. It looks something like:

```
const spec = [
    { //1
        name: "Field 1",
        start: 1,
        width: 4,
        padding_position: "end",    
    },
    { //2
        name: "Field 2",
        type: "int",
        start: 5,
        width: 5,
        padding_symbol: "0",
    },
    { //3
        name: "Field 3",
        start: 10,
        width: 20,
        padding_position: "end",
    },
    {
        name: "Field 4",
        start: 30,
        width: 2,
        padding_position: "end",
    },
];
```

What I want is:

```
type FieldName = /* insert inference magic here */

const dataToSerialize: { [K in FieldName]?: string | number } = { "Field 1": "value" };
```

I get that I can define `FieldName` explicitly as `"Field 1" | "Field 2" | ...`, but in the interest of DRY, because I have lots of these, I'd prefer to infer the type constraints from the spec.

Extra special bonus if I can map from an optional `"type"` key in the object literal to an TypeScript type for the object value, instead of using `string | number`, but the first part is much more valuable to me.

Comment: You could [do this](https://tsplay.dev/wgBOlW) assuming you have some control over the declaration of your value.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] so the example code here is a [mre] instead of fragmentary (a bare array literal should be assigned somewhere) and/or pseudocode ( `{[FieldName]: string | number}` type is not valid TypeScript).

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the help and the feedback on making the example code valid. The type you provided does work for extracting the field names and getting `dataToSerialize` to type check. The issue I'm running into now is how to write a valid type definition for the serialization function. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wk3JDW). `unparse` is a 3rd party function, but I am writing my own `.d.ts` typedef for it, since it is untyped, so I can change that part as necessary. If you're able to help with that, I'd be glad to update the question or create a new one to capture the follow up issue.

Comment: @jcalz And def do feel free to answer with your solution for `type FieldName`. You nailed the question, as asked.

Comment: Followup questions probably belong in new posts so that we don't expand the scope of a question indefinitely.

Comment: @jcalz It feels a little hacky, but I was able to the typechecker to accept my work by defining my specification with `string` as a placeholder for the field type that I derive from the specification. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaZBpm). It feels like it shouldn't be allowed to work that way, but it does, and it solves my main problem of ensuring that when the data structure is being built for serialization, only valid field names are used.

Comment: Uhhh that [doesn't work](https://tsplay.dev/mxqVzW) I think since you get `string` and not the union you care about.  I'm not really prepared to hash this out in the comments since this feels like a different scope or a followup question.

Comment: @jcalz Yikes, yeah, the typechecking is effectively turned off. I think I've figured out a workaround, but I'll leave you alone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to possibly work you need to make sure that TypeScript keeps track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` properties; the code as you've written it will end up producing elements of a type like `{name: string}`, since that's the default assumption TypeScript makes when seeing string-valued object properties.  The easiest way to preserve that information is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on your array literal:

```
const spec = [ /* ✂ ⋯ ✂ */ ] as const;
```

which produces the type

```
/* const spec: readonly [{
    readonly name: "Field 1";
    readonly start: 1;
    readonly width: 4;
    readonly padding_position: "end";
}, {
    readonly name: "Field 2";
    readonly type: "int";
    readonly start: 5;
    readonly width: 5;
    readonly padding_symbol: "0";
}, ✂ ⋯ ✂ ] */
```

Then you can just [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the type of `spec` with `number` to get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of element types (TS assumes that indexing into an array with a `number`-valued key gives you one of its elements), and then index into that with `"name"` to get the union of `name` property literal types you want:

```
type FieldName = typeof spec[number]["name"];
// type FieldName = "Field 1" | "Field 2" | "Field 3" | "Field 4";
```

As for your "bonus" question you would need to actually [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the elements of your `spec` array.  The easiest way is to do that and [remap the key](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) of each element to its `name` property, and then check for the presence of a `type` property via a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type Bonus = { [T in typeof spec[number] as T["name"]]?: 
  T extends { type: infer U } ? U : string | number 
};
/* type Bonus = {
    "Field 1"?: string | number | undefined;
    "Field 2"?: "int" | undefined;
    "Field 3"?: string | number | undefined;
    "Field 4"?: string | number | undefined;
} */
```

This produces `"int"` instead of something else (presumably `number`)?  But hopefully you could figure out how to use that type to index into some mapping from names to types.  This is somewhat out of scope here anyway, so I'll stop now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAOBTYMC8MDaAoGMDeMA9IQIw64xgCGAtogFwwBEAYgJaIA2AJjCUwBpyuaFQBOURiSEUYAdzbcoAC0YAWGRXhVu3NmADmAfXggIbKG3CMmiMN0HkAvpoLEATMMq0Gzdl153R1koAE8kG30oYIpRCUYAVk1cBSVVGCSvbV19YwhQmgAjEE4bAAYYl3I3QgBmL2o6G38eGFqYkShxST4y5PlFFUZ3PqydPUMTMwsrMBs7B00q3DwGn2aOVrUOuC74ttHZVKGYd37sieNTc0trZgXKoQBdGCoIGFBIKABuLCxCABUH3A0DgSGAjDEiB04E4oUwq1kUJhYDh3iafk2vH4vyR0O4sPhcR6JFxFGRBNR8OO6TUZNwFMJMAuuSmN1m83sTF+LnwXkZVPRvlYWNO3P5+KZYQizCi4rxKLRxMS9JgArRNJVEsV8JZk3yRRK5XFvMRFAAdJaeQI+bJLeaeS8AYQ-tLEDAWtwAHI+NAwN0gABmYOQGDAAFciogxE8MExGogmE9fsR-eF3Z6fXQ-SKAnwmDAAD6YvNBIsl1rtcu5rbirCfUHcKhdAAqIAAytG2FROGwAF6+AgYADSMH0HqxWcQTwA-IxoGJcuWI1GxDAnH6CDXsUwbAA3HvhxPr35YN0wABC4HD73QQ5bY7AaaQQZDwDDkcK0aebxgLbjCZJrOjAPogAAeUALO8BBuow+iBtGMAAKrrjAM7ITA85QIuhjLp+iFOCmQLnleEa3raFDbvmc67DhBh4au5bhvYiCBvoiDcKqVFBDRTBykxLFsWAHFcZ6bRMDRC5LsWK5fmuxbMdwrHsZxXhUdsknYdJlD4fJMCKcpwmqRuzpAA)

Comment: Huge thanks, great explanation!

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the lookup to work. I tried instead of returning `U`, returning `SpecTypeMapping[U]`, where `SpecTypeMapping` is an interface that serves as a map from string to type. But this would be purely a nice to have, everything works fine without it.